# Add file name to email subject line and send email to the Last modified by/Author

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word

I have a Word document in which I placed a `CommandButton` on the document so that the user can send an Outlook email with a message, but I want the Subject of the email to be the name of the opened active Word document, so the Subject to be variable depending on the name of active document and email to the Author of that active doc Wd.

To identify the Last modified by/Author name and based on that name convert it into firstname.secondname@xyz.ro? The Author will send an email to his superior, and that doc Wd will be reviewed by this person via that `CommandButton`.

```
Public Sub Mail()
    Dim LastAuthor As String
        LastAuthor = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("last Author")

        Dim Email As String
            Email = Replace(LastAuthor, " ", ".") & "@btrl.ro"


    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .Display
        .Signature = "HTMLbody"
        .To = Email
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = ActiveDocument.Name
        '.Body = "AVIZAT. Multumesc mult"
        '.Attachments.Add ActiveDocument.FullName
        ' You can add other files by uncommenting the following line.
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        ' In place of the following statement, you can use ".Display" to
        ' display the mail.
        .HTMLbody = "AVIZAT" & "<br>" & .HTMLbody

        Dim objDoc As Document
        Set objDoc = ActiveDocument
        objDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        OutputFileName:=Replace(objDoc.FullName, ".docx", ".pdf"), _
        ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, _
        Range:=wdExportAllDocument, Item:=wdExportDocumentContent
        ' Add the attachment first for correct attachment's name with non English symbols
        .Attachments.Add PdfFile.FullName

        .send
        MsgBox "E-mail trimis cu succes"

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the document name that’s on the commandButton?

Comment: Hi, 0m3r, please, can you help me with my last request? Now my converted document in .pdf is saved to desktop, and last thing is to be attached to the body of e-mail, but HTML signature to remain. I see this line of code ".Attachments.Add PdfFile.FullName" but the .pdf still is not attached. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Should be.*

```
.Subject = ThisDocument.Name
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.document.name

*If a document is not yet named, this property returns the document's temporary name*

---

**Edit**

**Per Comment below**

*Example*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim LastAuthor As String
        LastAuthor = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("last Author")

        Debug.Print LastAuthor ' Print on Immediat Window, Crtl-G

        Dim Email As String
            Email = Replace(LastAuthor, " ", ".") & "@email.com"

        Debug.Print Email ' Print on Immediat Window, Crtl-G

End Sub
```

*[BuiltinDocumentProperties Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.builtindocumentproperties?view=vsto-2017)*

*This property returns the entire collection of built-in document properties*

Comment: Wrong! That only references the document the code is being run from (e.g. a Word template), not the *active* document.

Comment: What if the op has  multiple active documents- this is the best option.

Comment: Even with multiple documents, the userform is liable to be in a template and the intention/expectation would be to employ the active document. Indeed, as the OP clearly stated: "I want the Subject of the email to be *the name of the opened active Word document*".

Comment: Can you help me please to modify the line of code .TO: in order to send an email to the Author of that active doc Wd,, to identify the Last modified by/Author name and based on that name convert it into firstname.secondname@xyz.ro? The Author will send an email to his superior, and that doc Wd will be reviewed by this person via that CommandButton.  Thank you very much for all your support!

Comment: Hi 0m3r, for initial question, it works fine with the changes made according to macroprod. Please, can you help me with my other issue? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I'm not allowed, only after 3 day, this is the message I receive when I want to post new question :(

Comment: I'm new to this, can u be more explicit where do I insert this code, before which line in my initial code? Pls

Comment: I've inserted the lines before my initial macro line "On Error Resume Next", I've rune the macro with F8, but it doesn't brig back nothing into line .TO=" "

Comment: Ok, inserted new macro accordingly, it creates the email BUT without firestname.secondname, brings back only @email.com

Comment: @Fane does the document has author name?

Comment: Yes! With little tweaks it works wonderful! Thank you so much for helping me!! Your input and feedback was excellent!

Comment: One last thing, if I want this Active document.docx (opened) to be converted to .pdf and attached into this replied mail to Author?

Comment: I managed to insert some lines of code with which exports active doc to .pdf with same name, but doesn't attach it tot the body, and also to keep the HTML signature. Attached the new code above, initial post. Tks

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
.Subject = ActiveDocument.Name
```